# How to redirect from plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

My plugin init function:

```
function init(){

    craft()->entries->onSaveEntry = function(Event $event) {

        //redirect to wanted url

    };

}
```

Is there a fancy way to redirect to my plugin url if, for example the entry channel is jobs.

Or I have to use header() function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [HttpRequestService](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService):

```
craft()->request->redirect($myAwesomeUrl);
```

Answer (score 11):

In Craft 3 we are looking at something similar to:

```php
Craft::$app->getResponse()->redirect(UrlHelper::cpUrl('settings/plugins/craft-mailchimp'))->send();
```